# How to Filter linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am able to filter the data with the following two parameters id1 and id2, and get accurate result of 10 records, from which have 9 with a price_type=cs and other with price-type=ms.

However, if I add price_type to the parameters id1 and id2 (id1=23456,567890&id2=6782345&price_type=ms), I get 3000 records instead of getting one record.

Am I missing something in the code. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
        var data = db.database_BWICs.AsQueryable();
        var filteredData = new List<IQueryable<database_Data>>();


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
        {
            var ids = query.name.Split(',');
            foreach (string i in ids)
            {
                filteredData.Add(data.Where(c => c.Name != null && c.Name.Contains(i)));
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.id2))
        {
            var ids = query.id2.Split(',');
            foreach (string i in ids)
            {
                filteredData.Add(data.Where(c => c.ID2!= null && c.ID2.Contains(i)));
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.id1))
        {
            var ids = query.id1.Split(',');
            foreach (string i in ids)
            {
                filteredData.Add(data.Where(c => c.ID1!= null && c.ID1.Contains(i)));
            }
        }

        if (query.price_type != null)
        {
            var ids = query.price_type.Split(',');
            foreach (string i in ids)
            {
                filteredData.Add(data.Where(c => c.Type.Contains(i)));
            }
        }

        if (filteredData.Count != 0)
        {
            data = filteredData.Aggregate(Queryable.Union);
        }
```

Updated Code:

```
 var data = db.database_BWICs.AsQueryable();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
        {
            var ids = query.name.Split(',');
            data = data.Where(c => c.Name != null && ids.Contains(c.Name));
         }

        if (query.price_type != null)
        {
            var ids = query.price_type.Split(',');
            data = data.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.Cover));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query.id1))
        {
            var ids = query.id1.Split(',');
            data = data.Where(c => c.ID1!= null && ids.Contains(c.ID1));
        }
```

Comment: What results do you get if you run separate queries for the `id1` and `id2` parameters on their own?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response.  I get correct records of data when I run id1 and id2 query separately. Eg.(api/test?id1=5683028) (api/test?id2=7982377).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't add filter to restrict, every filter adds datas to result.

It means you make OR between your filters, not AND.

And your usage of contains looks rather strange too : you're using `String.Contains`, while I would guess (maybe wrong) that you want to see if a value is in a list => `Enumerable.Contains`

You should rather go for something like this (withoud `filteredData`)

```
var data = db.database_BWICs.AsQueryable();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
{
    var ids = query.name.Split(',');
    data = data.Where(c => c.Name != null && ids.Contains(c.Name)));
}
//etc.

if (query.price_type != null)
{
     var ids = query.price_type.Split(',');
     data = data.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.Type));
}
```

**EDIT**

Well, if you wanna mix and or conditions, you could go for [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Then your code should look like that (to be tested).

```
//manage the queries with OR clause first
var innerOr = Predicate.True<database_BWICs>();//or the real type of your entity

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query.id1))
{
    var ids = query.id1.Split(',');
    innerOr = innerOr.Or(c => c.ID1!= null && ids.Contains(c.ID1));
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query.id2))
{
    var ids = query.id2.Split(',');
    innerOr = innerOr.Or(c => c.ID2!= null && ids.Contains(c.ID2));
}
//now manage the queries with AND clauses
var innerAnd = Predicate.True<database_BWICs>();//or the real type of your entity

if (query.price_type != null)
{
    var ids = query.price_type.Split(',');
    innerAnd = innerAnd.And(c => ids.Contains(c.Type));
}
//etc.

innerAnd = innerAnd.And(innerOr);

var data = db.database_BWICs.AsQueryable().Where(innerAnd);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I have tired using the same method as above before and using contains multiple times within the parameters, gives me 'no data error'

Comment: Dear @Raphael, If you get time, could you please have a look at this issue, I am still experiencing data filtering issues. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @user3070072 where do you get the no data error ? Could you try to debug step by step ?

Comment: I have tired debugging it many times and I always get the same error "{System.Data.Entity.DbSet<API.database_BWICs>}" and it with your code suggestion the code was falling on the data variable of id1.

Comment: please post the complete stack trace of exception in your question, hard to understand this in comment.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have a copied my debugging result in the question above, if your get time could you please suggest any solution to why I cannot use multiple contains for id1 and id2.

Comment: @user3070072 ok. What should this query retrieve : all datas where `(id1 = '00889VAC1' OR id1 = '026932AC7') OR id2 = 'US00889VAC19'` or all datas where `(id1 = '00889VAC1' OR id1 = '026932AC7') AND id2 = 'US00889VAC19'` ? Cause there's maybe just no corresponding datas...

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The query should retrieve the following ((id1 = '00889VAC1' OR id1 = '026932AC7') OR id2 = 'US00889VAC19')) but if there is parameter such as price_type or deal_type then it should be able to retrieve something like ((id1 = '00889VAC1' OR id1 = '026932AC7') OR id2 = 'US00889VAC19')and price_type = cs. I really appreciate your support and time.

Comment: @user3070072 well, little bit more complicated. See edit, that might work for you. The problem was that your query was doing OR between all clauses, while mine was making AND.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time.  I am sorry to inform, but I am experiencing an error (Using the generic type 'System.Predicate<T>' requires 1 type arguments) on the (predicate) line code.

Comment: @user3070072 it's not `System.Predicate<T>`. You should read carefully the link I gave you on PredicateBuilder (you'll need to copy some code or add some reference, see "PredicateBuilder Source Code" part.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and I shall have go working with the 'predicate' function and try to resolve my my error 'System.Predicate<T>' and get the code to work.  I really appreciate your time and very thankful for your support.